# python sympy solve to do system of equation, but on my last solve I keep getting a TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'type'

Tags: python, sympy

```
import sympy 
from sympy import cos, sin
import math
P = 30  
d = 216  
h = 162 
angle = (math.atan(h/d))

FAY, FAX, FDY, GD, DC, GC, GF = sympy.S('FAY, FAX, FDY, GD, DC, GC, GF')

eqnx = FAX
eqny = FAY - P - P + FDY
eqnm = -(d*P) + -(3*d*P) + (4*d*FDY)
ans1 = sympy.solve((eqnx, eqny,eqnm), (FAX, FAY, FDY))
FAX = ans1[FAX]
FAY = ans1[FAY]
FDY = ans1[FDY]
print(ans1)

eqnDx = -GD*cos(angle)-DC
eqnDy = FDY + GD*sin(angle)
ans2 = sympy.solve((eqnDx, eqnDy), (GD, DC))
GD = ans2[GD]
DC = ans2[DC]
print(GD,DC)
print(ans2)

eqnGx = -(GF) + GD*cos(angle)
eqnGy = -(GC) + (-1)*(GD*sin(angle))
ans3 = sympy.solve((eqnGx, eqnGy), (GF, GC))
print(ans3)
```

I am getting an error on the line in  eqnGx = -(GF) + GD*cos(radians(angle))
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'type'
I was wondering if you guys have any clue to on how to fix the error.

Comment: The code is incomplete. What is `P`?

Comment: The problem seems to be that sympy defines `GF`  as `sympy.polys.domains.pythonfinitefield.PythonFiniteField`.  You really need to declare the variables using `sympy.symbols()`, not `sympy.S()`.  So:`FAY, FAX, FDY, GD, DC, GC, GF = sympy.symbols('FAY, FAX, FDY, GD, DC, GC, GF')`

Comment: The error `bad operand type for unary -: 'type'` sounds weird. This is because the type of `GF` is just called `type`.  Try `print(type(GF))`.